# Как перейти через браузер по данному мне vps провайдером IP?

Tags: администрирование, ip, vps, vds

Мне vps провайдер дал ip, логин и пароль для входа. Через ssh успешно захожу в консоль управления сервером. Но через браузер по данному IP зайти не могу. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: На сервере имеется какая-то web панель управления? Или что именно Вы ожидаете увидеть через браузер?

Comment: Нет, не имеется ничего. Есть просто голая консоль ubuntu. Как мне сделать, что бы увидеть через браузер хоть что-то?

Comment: @Вячеслав установить веб-сервер. Например nginx или apache2

Comment: @Вячеслав Надо было Windows Server брать.

Comment: @Rou1997 тупой ответ. Мог бы пройти мимо.

Comment: @Вячеслав На брудершафт не пили, а Windows гораздо удобнее и проще, и это факт, или то, что Билл Гейтс был самым богатым человеком на Земле, и почему ни Google, Canonical, ни Apple не могли подобным похвастаться - это тоже тупость?

Answer (score 0):

Все. Нашёл решение! У меня сервер работает на NodeJS. Программа слушала порт 5000, а браузер отображает на 80 порту. Так что тут 2 решения: 
1. Добавить в адресной строке браузера к IP порт.
2. Изменить в настройках программы порт на 80.
Теперь все работает на ура.